# How to create methods dynamically in Python ( name + code )

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying add new methods dynamically in python in the constructor ...

## Context

I wrote a Python module in C++ that interacts with my signal processing libraries written in C ...
I have generic method to access my modules (called *filters*) parameters.

Eg.:

```
int my_filter_set( void * filter_handle, const char * method_id, void * p_arg );
```

So my cpython wraps it like this :

```
filter.set(method_id,value)
```

And I have access to all my *method ids*.

```
>>> filter.setters
['SampleRate','...']
```

## Goal

I would like to generate setters like :

```
>>> filter.setSampleRate(value)
```

in a derived class.

```
class Filter(BaseFilter):
'''
classdocs
'''

def __init__(self, name, library):
    '''
    Constructor
    '''
    BaseFilter.__init__(self,name,library)

    for setter_id in self.setters:
        code = 'self.set(' + setter_id + ',value)'
        # @todo add the method body to a new method called 'set' + method_id (with 'value' as argument)
```

## Questions are ...

- Is it possible ?
- With python types module ?
- How to do it ?

> I already checked [this](http://snipplr.com/view/17819/) but I don't see the way I can adapt it to my purpose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than create the methods dynamically, you can check for method names that match your `setters` and then *dispatch* dynamically to your `set()` method. This can be achieved by overriding `__getattribute__()` in your `Filter` class:

```
class BaseFilter(object):
    setters = ('SampleRate', 'Gain', 'BitDepth',)

    def set(self, method_id, value):
        print 'BaseFilter.set(): setting {} to {}'.format(method_id, value)

class Filter(BaseFilter):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        method_id = name.lstrip('set')
        if name.startswith('set') and method_id in super(Filter, self).setters:
            def _set(value):
                return self.set(method_id, value)
            return _set
        else:
            return super(Filter, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

Here, for methods that are to be dispatched to `BaseFilter.set()`,  `__getattribute__()` returns a wrapped version of `BaseFilter.set()` that has access to the `method_id` in a closure.

---

```
>>> f = Filter()
>>> f.setSampleRate(44000)
BaseFilter.set(): setting SampleRate to 44000
>>> f.setBitDepth(16)
BaseFilter.set(): setting BitDepth to 16
>>> f.setGain(100)
BaseFilter.set(): setting Gain to 100

>>> f.setHouseOnFire(999)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in __getattribute__
AttributeError: 'Filter' object has no attribute 'setHouseOnFire'
```

Comment: @GarciaSylvain : great. I was quite pleased with it too!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your setter method names are available before the class definition is first encountered, if so, using a meta class to create the class might be appropriate. If they're only available at runtime, then this answer should direct you the way to your solution: [Adding a Method to an Existing Object Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object)

Answer (score 0):

From your description I cannot tell whether you looking for a way to create Python functions at run time or you're looking for a way to [provide Python bindings for your existing code base](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages).  There are many ways to make your code available to Python programmers.